# how can i simplify or get performance in this if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

this is the statement

```
if( validator(foo) && foo.var1 || foo.var2 || foo.var3 || foo.var4){
    //do sometihng
}else{
    //do anything because if foo.*  doesnt exists i cant do anything
}
```

the statement says: validator have to valid foo, and return true, and var1 or var2 var3 or var4 have to exists.

if someone needs an explanation, just add a commentary. This is a simple question, but im trying to get performance in my code.

by the way. There is any book or tutorial that has some info about performance code in javascript.??

thank you all!

Comment: Do you know this code is slow?

Comment: Rather out of date at this point, but this does lay down a good foundation: http://www.amazon.com/Performance-JavaScript-Faster-Application-Interfaces/dp/059680279X

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `validator(foo)` is an expensive operation, you can reverse the order of the tests:

```
if ((foo.var1 || foo.var2 || foo.var3 || foo.var4) && validator(foo)) {
} else {
}
```

If `validator(foo)` isn't particularly expensive, there probably is no reason to spend any time at all thinking about how to improve the performance of this little piece of code. There are better uses for your time.

By the way, this code is based on your verbal description. Your code as it stands is incompatible with the verbal description and is likely buggy. In JavaScript, `false && false || true` evaluates to `true`. You probably need

```
if( validator(foo) && (foo.var1 || foo.var2 || foo.var3 || foo.var4)) {
```

Also, as Benjamin points out, `foo.var1` does not test that `foo.var1` exists; it checks that it exists (either in `foo` or in its prototype chain) and furthermore is not a "falsy" value. (For instance, if `foo.var1` is 0, then it will evaluate as `false`.) You might be looking for `foo.hasOwnProperty('var1')`, etc.

Comment: Also, `foo.var1` and all its friends don't check for existence of a property on the object. They check for having all these properties somewhere on the prototype chain __and__ that they are all not falsy.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - Good point. It's hard to know exactly what OP is trying to accomplish with this code.

Comment: ok may be there is no a complete question, and a hard desription... but your answer solve me the problem tnx!